GEE data for Pakistan
I am trying to make map of flood with all the features like affected population and affected urban area. I already made one for Swat region Pakistan for 2022 using Sentinel 2 but while making the same one for Swat region Pakistan for 2010. I can't find the suitable Landsat for Swat region Pakistan.
var s1Collection = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S1_GRD')
  .filterBounds(ROI)
  .filter(ee.Filter.eq('instrumentMode', 'IW'))
  .filter(ee.Filter.listContains('transmitterReceiverPolarisation', 'VH'))
  .filter(ee.Filter.eq('orbitProperties_pass', 'DESCENDING'))
  .filter(ee.Filter.eq('resolution_meters', 10))
  .select('VH');

I used this code but for Landsat it showed half swat area or area with a lot of noise.

Can you confirm if this is the same with all the data captured at specified timeline via USGS?

Actually i am not sure. Because on the USGS WEBSITE if i am trying to download the data it shows error i have been trying for months i even mailed them but no response
